# SuiteScript getting value from a saved search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm having an issue pulling the value of a column in SuiteScript v1.0.  The search is looking at Cash Sales and is producing the results I want in the UI, but I am unable to get the value of one column in SuiteScript.  I suspect it is because either the value comes from the 'Created From' doc, or because it is a drop down list.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The search looks at Cash Sales where the Dept/Sales Channel (NS id department) doesn't match the Dept/Sales Channel of the Sales Order.  The results are:

1. Type
2. Document Number
3. Created From : Dept/Sales Channel

In the UI, it is doing exactly what I hoped.  However, when I loop thru the results in my v1.0 SuiteScript, I'm getting a null value for Dept/Sales Channel:

```
results.forEachResult(function(res){
        var id = res.getId();
        var docid = res.getValue('tranid');
        var dept = res.getValue('channel');
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Found result - '+docid+' ('+id+') - '+dept+'.');
```

docid and id are correct, but dept ends up being null.  I've tried 'channel', 'deptartment' and column[3].value with no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you formatted this: "Created From : Dept/Sales Channel", I assume it is a joined column.

If it is, you need to do it this way:

```
var dept = res.getValue('department', "createdfrom");
```